# Reformatting Survey Data in Ex

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to find a way to reformat results of a survey that are currently being exported to a spreadsheet in multiple rows per respondent (1 row per question, with a column indicating the respondent's ID, the ID of the question, and the response) so that we can provide a version with only one row per respondent (1 column per question, with the cell value of that column being that respondent's response).

In its simplest form, the problem is changing this table:

[image: example starting data]

into this one:

[image: example reformatted data]

This would need to be extendable so as to support an arbitrary number of IDs and questions, but the ID's are all unique, the questions are always labeled the same way, and the response is always in the same column. Building the columns manually is not an issue, assuming I can just copy the same basic method and replace the question value.

Comment: if you change your no/yes to 0/1, then a pivot table will get you there.

Answer (score 1):

Easily done with `Power Query` available in Excel 2010+

- With your cursor in the data table, in Excel 2016+ you would navigate to
   `Data-->Get&Transform-->From Table/Range`
   *(might be different in earlier versions)*
- Add a custom column which prefixes each question number with the word "Question "

[image]

- Remove the extraneous columns
- Pivot on the Custom Column, but do not Aggregate:

[image]

- Close and Load

[image]

**M Code**
*(you can paste this into the PQ Advanced Editor, but you'll have to change the Table reference in Line 2 to reflect your actual table name)*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table8"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Question", type text}, {"Response", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each "Question " & [Question]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Question"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Custom]), "Custom", "Response")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=LOOKUP(1,0/(($A$2:$A$5=$A10)*($B$2:$B$5=VALUE(RIGHT(B$9,1)))),$C$2:$C$5)
```

[image]